# Timeout Android Genexus

Tags: android, genexus

Boa tarde,

Gostaria de saber como validar a sessão no SD, ou seja, Timeout Genexus Android?

No Momento que finalizar o tempo, validar e voltar ao login, algo desse tipo?

Obrigado.

Comment: Você já tem alguma coisa pronta @MatheusPrimon ?, procure informar mais detalhes e de uma lida em :http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour, para formular perguntas com um exemplo minimo.

Comment: Matheus, Esta utilizando o GAM ? At. Filipe